# Regex too greedy Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to retrieve some parts from a single line html string.
The Regex I wrote is as follows:

```
String pattern = "rel=\"bookmark\">(.*?)</a></h2>"
```

The html line is like:

```
....rel="bookmark">what I need</a></h2>....rel="bookmark">....rel="bookmark">What I also need</a></h2>....
```

My Regex has two results:

```
rel="bookmark">what I need</a>
and
rel="bookmark">....rel="bookmark">What I also need</a></h2>
```

How can I tell it to be less greedy for the second result?

Comment: [Related question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191573/regex-multiple-occurrences-in-one-line). Look, you have HTML and you are using a regex. And you ask one question after another. Conclusion: Use an HTML parser. ["Regex is not the best tool for that task."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg).

Comment: I think you should get an appropriate answer for your original question.

Comment: Even though I should be better off with an HTML parser, my question still remains how you would be less greedy in Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between tags are the things does not contains `<` and `>`

```
String pattern = "rel=\"bookmark\">[^<>]+</a>";
```